# C++20 thread possibly waiting on std::atomic forever

Tags: c++, c++20, atomic, wait, stdatomic

Consider the following example code where thread A pushes functions on a queue and thread B executes those when popping from the queue:

```cpp
std::atomic<uint32_t> itemCount;

//Executed by thread A
void run(std::function<void()> function) {

    if (queue.push(std::move(function))) {
        itemCount.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
        itemCount.notify_one();
    }

}


//Executed by thread B
void threadMain(){

    std::function<void()> function;

    while(true){

        if (queue.pop(function)) {

            itemCount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
            function();

        }else{
            itemCount.wait(0, std::memory_order_acquire);
        }

    }

}
```

where `queue` is a concurrent queue which has a `push` and a `pop` function, each returning a `bool` indicating whether the given operation was successful. So `push` returns `false` if it's full and `pop` returns `false` if it's empty.

Now I was wondering if the code is thread-safe under all circumstances.
Let's suppose thread B's `pop` fails and is about to invoke `std::atomic<T>::wait`. At the same time, thread A pushes a new element while thread B checks the initial wait condition. Since `itemCount` hasn't changed yet, it fails.

Immediately after that, thread A increments the counter and tries to notify one waiting thread (although thread B doesn't wait internally yet). Thread B finally waits on the atomic, causing the thread to never wake up again due to the lost signal *despite there being an element in the queue*. That only stops as soon as a new element is being pushed on the queue, notifying B to continue execution.

I wasn't able to reproduce this situation manually since the timing is close to impossible to get right.

**Is this a serious concern or impossible to happen? What (preferably atomic) alternatives do exist in order to account for such rare situations?**

EDIT:
Just to mention, the queue is not blocking and only utilizes atomic operations.

---

The reason I'm asking is I don't understand how it's possible to implement an atomic `wait` operation. Although the standard says the whole operation is atomic (consisting of a load + predicate check + wait), in the implementation I'm using `std::atomic<T>::wait` is implemented roughly as follows:

```
void wait(const _TVal _Expected, const memory_order _Order = memory_order_seq_cst) const noexcept {
    _Atomic_wait_direct(this, _Atomic_reinterpret_as<long>(_Expected), _Order);
}
```

where `_Atomic_wait_direct` is defined as

```
template <class _Ty, class _Value_type>
void _Atomic_wait_direct(
    const _Atomic_storage<_Ty>* const _This, _Value_type _Expected_bytes, const memory_order _Order) noexcept {
    const auto _Storage_ptr = _STD addressof(_This->_Storage);
    for (;;) {
        const _Value_type _Observed_bytes = _Atomic_reinterpret_as<_Value_type>(_This->load(_Order));
        if (_Expected_bytes != _Observed_bytes) {
            return;
        }

        __std_atomic_wait_direct(_Storage_ptr, &_Expected_bytes, sizeof(_Value_type), _Atomic_wait_no_timeout);
    }
}
```

We can clearly see that there is an atomic load with the specified memory order to check the state of the atomic itself. However, I don't see how the *whole operation* can be considered atomic since there is a comparision right before the call to `__std_atomic_wait_direct`.

With condition variables, the predicate itself is secured by a mutex but how is the atomic itself secured here?

Comment: The `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_acq_rel` are the possible problem here.  Without them, your described problem does not happen.  With them, I can't tell you.  And if you cannot prove your code correct without those flags, **don't use those flags**.

Comment: I already suspected this to be an issue, but why exactly is `memory_order_seq_cst` safe in this case?

Comment: If there are others like me who wonder in what alternate universe C++ `atomic` has condition variable like apis the answer is this universe in C++20 [Difference between std::atomic and std::condition_variable wait, notify_* methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859596/difference-between-stdatomic-and-stdcondition-variable-wait-notify-method)

Comment: Seems to me you're trying to use an `std::atomic<uint32_t>` as a counting semaphore. I'd just use an `std::counting_semaphore>` instead. I'd also build that into the queue itself, so `push` and `pop` deal with it, and the outside world doesn't. As an aside, I'd also pass a timeout to the `pop`, so it'll automatically wait up to som specified amount of time before failing.

Comment: @Overblade I can reason about `memory_order_seq_cst`, so I can show that your scenario cannot happen; I mean, read how `wait` works.  I cannot reliably reason about `acquire` or `acq_rel`, so I cannot say anything of note (I do not fully understand how they work).  I claim that if you cannot see that `memory_order_seq_cst` is safe, then maybe you shouldn't be using the more exotic memory model flags.

Comment: I am aware of how `memory_order_seq_cst` works, but still looking at the implementation of `wait` I don't think it can guarantee it can't happen. Actually, this is not a matter of atomicity itself; as I said the first load in wait (the predicate) could receive 0, then `fetch_add` sets it to 1 so that still the notify could be issued before the wait to the OS. I might be horribly off, but I want to justify at least *why* I think memory ordering isn't the main issue.

Comment: @Overblade Without sequential consistency, do you know if you'll see the +1 being set before you see the notification arriving?  I don't know.  With it, I do.

Comment: Exactly. But that misses the point. Like I said, it's not necessarily about ordering here. Consider the case I proposed. Take the strongest ordering, no optimizations at all. Can you *guarantee* that the notify happens after the wait call into the OS considering all possible timings between operations in the two threads?

Comment: `wait` is an atomic operation, and so is `fetch_add`. They don't interleave, but execute in some global order. If `wait` happens to execute first, then it would be followed by `fetch_add` and `notify_all`, which would wake it up. If `fetch_add` happens to execute first, then by the time `wait` is executed, `itemCount.load() != 0` and `wait` will return immediately. You think of `wait` as executing in steps - check the value of the atomic, then enter the wait - but that's as wrong as thinking that `fetch_add` fetches first then adds, and worrying that another operation would squeeze in between.

Comment: If that's the case, then indeed there is no way the described situation could ever happen. Seems like I got confused by the standard library's code because the whole function itself didn't look like one atomic operation. Oh well.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That is definitely true with sequential consistency.  But without sequential consistency, what guarantee do you have that the thread doing the wait doesn't "see" the notify *before* the increment?  The OP explicitly asked things are allowed to happen out of sequence.  Do you know that the aquire/release and notify rules still provide sufficient guarantees?  I don't.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I'm skeptical that it's that simple.  I've been doing some tests that suggest that (on a common implementation), if you have a `x.fetch_add(1, memory_order_seq_cst)` followed by a `y.load(memory_order_relaxed)`, the load can be reordered in between the load and store of the `fetch_add()`.  The `x.fetch_add()` is atomic in the sense that no stores to `x` can come between its load and store, and that other observers will not see intermediate values for `x`, but AFAIK the atomicity isn't related to its ordering.

Comment: In that case, it's reasonable to wonder whether `itemCount.notify_one()` could also be reordered in between the load and store of `itemCount.fetch_add()`, which would appear to cause this algorithm to deadlock.

Comment: @NateEldredge I added an answer with the detailed analysis. See if you find it convincing.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I added an answer with the detailed analysis. See if you find it convincing.

Comment: If you just spin until `queue.pop` returns `true` you don't need that `itemCount` at all.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I really want to avoid spinning if possible. Some implementations of `std::atomic` default to a short spin, then revert to something less-busy (e.g. libstdc++ from gcc). Of course there is no guarantee but I prefer a solution that at least *allows* non-spinning too.

Comment: If you'd like to avoid spinning you should use a blocking queue, possibly with a spin-mutex, rather than trying to invent a blocking `pop` for a non-blocking queue.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what the standard has to say:

> **[intro.races]/4** All modifications to a particular atomic object `M` occur in some particular total order, called the modification order of `M`.

> **[atomics.wait]/4** A call to an atomic waiting operation on an atomic object `M` is *eligible to be unblocked* by a call to an atomic notifying operation on `M` if there exist side effects `X` and `Y` on `M` such that:
> (4.1) — the atomic waiting operation has blocked after observing the result of `X`,
> (4.2) — `X` precedes `Y` in the modification order of `M`, and
> (4.3) — `Y` happens before the call to the atomic notifying operation.

You posit the following scenario:

1. The current value of `itemCount` is zero, either from original initialization or a previous `fetch_sub`.
2. `wait` loads `itemCount` and observes the value of 0.
3. The other thread calls `fetch_add` and `notify_one`
4. `wait` goes blocking, as it believes the now-stale value of 0.

In this scenario, `M` is `itemCount`, `X` is the old `fetch_sub` that brought the value to 0 (we assume that it happened long ago and is properly visible to all threads) and `Y` is the `fetch_add` that changes the value to 1.

The standard says that the `wait` call (spanning steps 2 and 4) is in fact eligible to be unblocked by `notify_one` call on step 3. Indeed:

(4.1) - `wait` has blocked after observing `itemCount == 0` (if it has not, then the problem fails to arise).
(4.2) - `fetch_sub` precedes `fetch_add` in the modification order of `itemCount` (by assumption that `fetch_sub` happened long ago).
(4.3) - `fetch_add` happens before (in fact, is sequenced before) `notify_one`; they are called one after the other by the same thread.

Therefore, a conforming implementation must either not allow `wait` to block in the first place, or have `notify_one` wake it up; it cannot allow the notification to be missed.

---

The only place where memory orders figure in this discussion is in (4.1), "the atomic waiting operation has blocked after **observing** the result of `X`". Perhaps `fetch_add` actually occurred before `wait` (by wall clock), but was not visible to `wait`, so it went blocking anyway. But it doesn't matter to the outcome - either `wait` observes the result of `fetch_add` and doesn't block at all; or it observes the result of the old `fetch_sub` and blocks, but then `notfiy_one` is required to wake it up.

Comment: So, I guess the point is that *eligible to be unblocked by* permits fairly weak ordering.  Loading the result of X, where X precedes Y in modification order, does not prove that your load happened-before Y, but happens-before isn't what *eligible to be unlocked by* requires.

Comment: Such a clarifying answer -- thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Just to point out what may have led to the confusion in the first place: the function `__std_atomic_wait_direct`, *all by itself*, does the compare and block in an atomic fashion.  It boils down to either a call to [`WaitOnAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress), or else [uses a condition variable](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/6d2f8b0ed88ea6cba26cc2151f47f678442c1663/stl/src/atomic_wait.cpp#L287), where the compare is done while holding the associated mutex.

The `if (_Expected_bytes != _Observed_bytes)` is merely an optimization.  If the variable is *already* different from the expected value, we can return right away without making the relatively expensive call to an underlying atomic function.  It doesn't need to be atomic with the block, and could be removed altogether without affecting the semantics.